# Glass Cast Failing With Infer Type True On Second Call

Tags: glass-mapper, caching

I'm using SitecoreContext.Cast(item, true, true) to map an item. It looks like elsewhere in the code, the same item has been casted to BaseType WITHOUT inferType = true before I make that call. When I do the next call with inferType = true, I'm getting the item back as a BaseType, instead of the inferred type. It appears that the item is being placed in the cache as BaseType, and the inferType = true call gets the item from the cache without inferring the type.

Is there something missing here, or a way to tell the Glass cache that it needs to pull the correct type out of the cache?

Comment: Hum this might be a bug, we use https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/blob/master/Source/Glass.Mapper.Sc/Caching/CacheKeyGenerator.cs  to generate the cache key but I wonder if the RequestedType is incorrect. Can you log a bug on Github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try overriding the CacheKeyGenerator with the following class:

```
public class CacheKeyGenerator : ICacheKeyGenerator
{
    public string Generate(ObjectConstructionArgs args)
    {
        var context = args.AbstractTypeCreationContext as SitecoreTypeCreationContext;

        return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}",
            context.SitecoreService.GlassContext.Name,
            Sitecore.Context.Site == null ? string.Empty : Sitecore.Context.Site.Name,
            context.Item.ID,
            context.Item["__Revision"],
            context.Item.Language.Name,
            context.Item.Database.Name,
            args.Configuration.Type.FullName,
            context.IsLazy
            );
    }
}
```

Let me know if this fixes the issue because I think this is a bug.

Comment: I had found a temporary work around and wasn't able to get back to this issue until yesterday. I tested it and this did indeed fix the issue. Thanks!